# Testing app by installing it on different devices?

Tags: ios, iphone

For testing browsers in different OS and different browser(versions), we can use browserstack. Is there anything similar thing, so that we can select device and install the app from app store and test?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ripple Emulator Chrome Extension 
[Ripple Emulator at Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)

Was using it previously and it did a quite a nice job. Obviously its not as good as browserstack, but definitely helps a lot checking different sizes of screens and some of other page behaviour.